# After Handling Exception in Kernel Returning to User Text

Tags: assembly, exception, kernel, overflow, mips

I created my own error handling in the `.ktext` portion of my code. My program properly goes there when an arithmetic overflow occurs but when I want it to return to the code via the `eret` code however does not return properly. When it returns it jumps to the clean portion, cleans the registers but will not properly print or restart as I have attempted to program it to. Can anyone please tell me the flaw in my method?

**NOTE** I've noticed that in the output it does actually restart the program but none of my .data portion of strings are being outputted correctly, they are being outputted as symbols. **NOTE**

Here is my code: 
after the kernel handles the exception it jumps back to the addition location where it then sees that I set $s6 to zero and cleans all the registers then jumps back to the start of my program. Is this the incorrect way of restarting the program and asking the user for a smaller input? My goal is to program it with this type of error handling.

```
## Daniel Revie 
## 2/8/2016



.data 0x10000000
.align 2
Array1: .word 0:9
str1: .asciiz "This is assignment 6 \n"
str2: .asciiz "The value of a["
str5: .asciiz "] is: "
str3: .asciiz "Arithmetic overflow"
str4: .asciiz "Enter n: "
str6: .asciiz "Arithmetic Overflow"
clean: .asciiz "clean occurs"

.text 0x00400000
.align 2
.globl main

main:



Restart:

## Print str1
li $v0, 4           # load 4 to $v0 to begin printing
la $a0, str1        # load address of string to be printed
syscall   

## Print str4
li $v0, 4
la $a0, str4
syscall

## Read in N
li $v0, 5
syscall 
move $t6, $v0
addi $t6, 1
addi $s6, $t6, -1

li $s6, 1 


## assign array values
addi $t0, $zero 0    # value 0
addi $t1, $zero 1    # value 1
addi $t2, $zero 2    # value 2
addi $t3, $zero 4    # value N = 4
#addi $t6, $zero 10   # End value a[9] is the 10th element

## byte addressing issue
mul $a0, $t0, $t3    # $t0 *4
mul $a1, $t1, $t3    # $t1 *4
mul $a2, $t2, $t3    # $t2 *4

## store first 3 elements of the array 
sw $t0, Array1($a0)  # a[0] = 0
sw $t1, Array1($a1)  # a[1] = 1
sw $t1, Array1($a2)  # a[2] = 1 

addi $v1 $zero 4    # get value 4

addi $t4, $zero 3
## begin loop algoirthm to generate rest of array values
Loop:


## End condition
beq $t4, $t6 END

## generate n - k
addi $t0, $t4 -1      # n-1
addi $t1, $t4 -2      # n-2
addi $t2, $t4 -3      # n-3

## byte addressing issue
 mul $t0, $t0, $v1    # $t0 *4
 mul $t1, $t1, $v1    # $t1 *4
 mul $t2, $t2, $v1    # $t2 *4

## store the values
lw $a0, Array1($t0)  # a[n-1]
lw $a1, Array1($t1)  # a[n-2]
lw $a2, Array1($t2)  # a[n-3]

## begin addition
add $t5, $a0 $a1      # a[n-1] + a[n-2]
beq $s7, $s6, Clean
add $t5, $t5 $a2      # a[n-1] + a[n-2] + a[n-3]
beq $s7, $s6, Clean

## save the result in the proper location
mul $a3 $t4 $v1       # $a3 = $t4 * 4
sw $t5, Array1($a3)

## increment N
addi $t4, $t4, 1

## repeat
j Loop


END:
mul $t6, $t6, $v1    # $t6 * 4
lw $t7, Array1($a3)

## print str2
li $v0, 4
la $a0, str2
syscall

## print value of answer 
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s6
syscall 

# print str5
li $v0, 4
la $a0, str5
syscall

## Print contents of $t7
addi $a0, $t7, 0    # Move the product to $a0
li $v0, 1           # code for printing register
syscall

j Finish

Clean:

li $t0, 0
li $t1, 0
li $t2, 0
li $t3, 0
li $t4, 0
li $t5, 0
li $t6, 0
li $t7, 0

li $s0, 0
li $s1, 0
li $s2, 0
li $s3, 0
li $s4, 0
li $s5, 0
li $s6, 0
li $s7, 0

li $v0, 0
li $v1, 0
li $a0, 0
li $a1, 0
li $a2, 0
li $a3, 0

j Restart




Finish:
## End program
li $v0, 10
syscall



## Begin arithmetic overflow handling
.ktext 0x80000180


## Print overflow message 
move $k0,$v0   # Save $v0 value
move $k1,$a0   # Save $a0 value
li $v0, 4
la $a0, kstr1
syscall
move $v0,$k0   # Restore $v0
move $a0,$k1   # Restore $a0
mfc0 $k0,$14   # Coprocessor 0 register $14 has address of trapping instruction
addi $k0,$k0,4 # Add 4 to point to next instruction
mtc0 $k0,$14   # Store new address back into $14

li $s7, 1

eret


.kdata
kstr1: .asciiz "Arithmetic overflow"
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of bugs. I've: (1) annotated your source with "BUG", (2) fixed the bugs, and (3) changed the exception algorithm.

---

Here's your original source, just bug annotations [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
# Daniel Revie
# 2/8/2016

    ###.data    0x10000000          # BUG: does weird things in mars
    ###.align   2
    .data
Array1:     .word       0:9
str1:       .asciiz     "This is assignment 6 \n"
str2:       .asciiz     "The value of a["
str5:       .asciiz     "] is: "
str3:       .asciiz     "Arithmetic overflow"
str4:       .asciiz     "Enter n: "
str6:       .asciiz     "Arithmetic Overflow"
clean:      .asciiz     "clean occurs"

    ###.text    0x00400000
    .text
    ###.align   2                   # BUG: flagged by assembler
    .globl  main

main:

restart:

    # Print str1
    li      $v0,4                   # load 4 to $v0 to begin printing
    la      $a0,str1                # load address of string to be printed
    syscall

    # Print str4
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str4
    syscall

    # Read in N
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $t6,$v0
    ###addi $t6,1                   # BUG: flagged -- invalid
    addi    $t6,$t6,1               # FIX: corrected
    addi    $s6,$t6,-1              # BUG: this gets trashed in next inst

    # BUG: no check is made for t6 exceeding the end of Array1
    # with large enough N, the stores below will overrun and destroy str1 et.
    # al. so that on a restart, the first string print will be garbage [as well
    # as any other messages]

    li      $s6,1                   # BUG: this never changes

    # assign array values
    addi    $t0,$zero,0             # value 0
    addi    $t1,$zero,1             # value 1
    addi    $t2,$zero,2             # value 2
    addi    $t3,$zero,4             # value N = 4
    # addi $t6, $zero, 10   # End value a[9] is the 10th element

    # byte addressing issue
    mul     $a0,$t0,$t3             # $t0 *4
    mul     $a1,$t1,$t3             # $t1 *4
    mul     $a2,$t2,$t3             # $t2 *4

    # store first 3 elements of the array
    sw      $t0,Array1($a0)         # a[0] = 0
    sw      $t1,Array1($a1)         # a[1] = 1
    sw      $t1,Array1($a2)         # a[2] = 1

    addi    $v1,$zero,4             # get value 4

    addi    $t4,$zero,3
# begin loop algoirthm to generate rest of array values
Loop:

    # End condition
    beq     $t4,$t6,END

    # generate n - k
    addi    $t0,$t4,-1              # n-1
    addi    $t1,$t4,-2              # n-2
    addi    $t2,$t4,-3              # n-3

    # byte addressing issue
    mul     $t0,$t0,$v1             # $t0 *4
    mul     $t1,$t1,$v1             # $t1 *4
    mul     $t2,$t2,$v1             # $t2 *4

    # store the values
    lw      $a0,Array1($t0)         # a[n-1]
    lw      $a1,Array1($t1)         # a[n-2]
    lw      $a2,Array1($t2)         # a[n-3]

    # begin addition
    add     $t5,$a0,$a1             # a[n-1] + a[n-2]
    beq     $s7,$s6,cleanup
    add     $t5,$t5,$a2             # a[n-1] + a[n-2] + a[n-3]
    beq     $s7,$s6,cleanup

    # save the result in the proper location
    mul     $a3,$t4,$v1             # $a3 = $t4 * 4
    sw      $t5,Array1($a3)

    # increment N
    addi    $t4,$t4,1

    # repeat
    j       Loop

END:
    mul     $t6,$t6,$v1             # $t6 * 4
    lw      $t7,Array1($a3)

    # print str2
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str2
    syscall

    # print value of answer
    # BUG -- answer is always 1
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s6
    syscall

    # print str5
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str5
    syscall

    # Print contents of $t7
    addi    $a0,$t7,0               # Move the product to $a0
    li      $v0,1                   # code for printing register
    syscall

    j       finish

cleanup:

    li      $t0,0
    li      $t1,0
    li      $t2,0
    li      $t3,0
    li      $t4,0
    li      $t5,0
    li      $t6,0
    li      $t7,0

    li      $s0,0
    li      $s1,0
    li      $s2,0
    li      $s3,0
    li      $s4,0
    li      $s5,0
    li      $s6,0
    li      $s7,0

    li      $v0,0
    li      $v1,0
    li      $a0,0
    li      $a1,0
    li      $a2,0
    li      $a3,0

    j       restart

finish:
    # End program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# Begin arithmetic overflow handling
    .ktext  0x80000180

    # Print overflow message
    move    $k0,$v0                 # Save $v0 value
    move    $k1,$a0                 # Save $a0 value
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,kstr1
    syscall
    move    $v0,$k0                 # Restore $v0
    move    $a0,$k1                 # Restore $a0
    mfc0    $k0,$14                 # Coproc 0 $14 has address of trapping inst

    # BUG: in the general case, this doesn't do much and hinges on the base
    # code testing the s7 value we set below
    # much better to fill $14 with the address of restart
    addi    $k0,$k0,4               # Add 4 to point to next instruction

    mtc0    $k0,$14                 # Store new address back into $14

    # BUG: this needs a comment to explain _why_ this is a corrective action
    # we should _not_ have to _infer_ it
    # BUG: this is a _weak_ response at best
    li      $s7,1

    eret

    .kdata
kstr1:      .asciiz     "Arithmetic overflow"
```

---

Here's the bug fix for the primary, "show stopper" bug:

```
# Daniel Revie
# 2/8/2016

###.data    0x10000000          # BUG: does weird things in mars
###.align   2
    .data

Array1:     .space      10000
    # BUG -- this was way too short (see below)
    ###Array1:      .word       0:9

str1:       .asciiz     "This is assignment 6 \n"
str2:       .asciiz     "The value of a["
str5:       .asciiz     "] is: "
str3:       .asciiz     "Arithmetic overflow"
str4:       .asciiz     "Enter n: "
str6:       .asciiz     "Arithmetic Overflow"
clean:      .asciiz     "clean occurs"

###.text    0x00400000
    .text
###.align   2                   # BUG: flagged by assembler
    .globl  main

main:

restart:

    # Print str1
    li      $v0,4                   # load 4 to $v0 to begin printing
    la      $a0,str1                # load address of string to be printed
    syscall

    # Print str4
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str4
    syscall

    # Read in N
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $t6,$v0
    ###addi $t6,1                   # BUG: flagged -- invalid
    addi    $t6,$t6,1               # FIX: corrected

    # BUG: no check is made for t6 exceeding the end of Array1
    # with large enough N, the stores below will overrun and destroy str1 et.
    # al. so that on a restart, the first string print will be garbage [as well
    # as any other messages]
    # FIX: increase size of Array1 from 10 words to something large enough
    # this is just a quick fix -- the correct one is to limit N to the size
    # of Array1

    li      $s6,1                   # BUG: this never changes

    # assign array values
    li      $t0,0                   # value 0
    li      $t1,1                   # value 1
    li      $t2,2                   # value 2
    li      $t3,4                   # value N = 4
    # li $t6,10   # End value a[9] is the 10th element

    # byte addressing issue
    mul     $a0,$t0,$t3             # $t0 *4
    mul     $a1,$t1,$t3             # $t1 *4
    mul     $a2,$t2,$t3             # $t2 *4

    # store first 3 elements of the array
    sw      $t0,Array1($a0)         # a[0] = 0
    sw      $t1,Array1($a1)         # a[1] = 1
    sw      $t1,Array1($a2)         # a[2] = 1

    li      $v1,4                   # get value 4

    li      $t4,3

# begin loop algorithm to generate rest of array values
loop:

    # End condition
    beq     $t4,$t6,done

    # generate n - k
    subi    $t0,$t4,1               # n-1
    subi    $t1,$t4,2               # n-2
    subi    $t2,$t4,3               # n-3

    # byte addressing issue
    mul     $t0,$t0,$v1             # $t0 *4
    mul     $t1,$t1,$v1             # $t1 *4
    mul     $t2,$t2,$v1             # $t2 *4

    # store the values
    lw      $a0,Array1($t0)         # a[n-1]
    lw      $a1,Array1($t1)         # a[n-2]
    lw      $a2,Array1($t2)         # a[n-3]

    # begin addition
    add     $t5,$a0,$a1             # a[n-1] + a[n-2]
    bnez    $s7,cleanup
    add     $t5,$t5,$a2             # a[n-1] + a[n-2] + a[n-3]
    bnez    $s7,cleanup

    # save the result in the proper location
    mul     $a3,$t4,$v1             # $a3 = $t4 * 4
    sw      $t5,Array1($a3)

    # increment N
    addi    $t4,$t4,1

    # repeat
    j       loop

done:
    mul     $t6,$t6,$v1             # $t6 * 4
    lw      $t7,Array1($a3)

    # print str2
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str2
    syscall

    # print value of answer
    # BUG -- answer is always 1
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s6
    syscall

    # print str5
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str5
    syscall

    # Print contents of $t7
    addi    $a0,$t7,0               # Move the product to $a0
    li      $v0,1                   # code for printing register
    syscall

    j       finish

cleanup:

    li      $t0,0
    li      $t1,0
    li      $t2,0
    li      $t3,0
    li      $t4,0
    li      $t5,0
    li      $t6,0
    li      $t7,0

    li      $s0,0
    li      $s1,0
    li      $s2,0
    li      $s3,0
    li      $s4,0
    li      $s5,0
    li      $s6,0
    li      $s7,0

    li      $v0,0
    li      $v1,0
    li      $a0,0
    li      $a1,0
    li      $a2,0
    li      $a3,0

    j       restart

finish:
    # End program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# Begin arithmetic overflow handling
    .ktext  0x80000180

    # Print overflow message
    move    $k0,$v0                 # Save $v0 value
    move    $k1,$a0                 # Save $a0 value
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,kstr1
    syscall
    move    $v0,$k0                 # Restore $v0
    move    $a0,$k1                 # Restore $a0
    mfc0    $k0,$14                 # Coproc 0 $14 has address of trapping inst

    # BUG: in the general case, this doesn't do much and hinges on the base
    # code testing the s7 value we set below
    # much better to fill $14 with the address of restart
    addi    $k0,$k0,4               # Add 4 to point to next instruction

    mtc0    $k0,$14                 # Store new address back into $14

    # BUG: this needs a comment to explain _why_ this is a corrective action
    # we should _not_ have to _infer_ it
    # this is a weak/fragile response at best as it only works for two places
    # above (e.g. this is hardwired)
    li      $s7,1

    eret

    .kdata
kstr1:      .asciiz     "\nhandler: Arithmetic overflow\n"
```

---

Here is a cleaner fix for the primary bug as well as [IMO] a different/better way to handle the exception:

```
# Daniel Revie
# 2/8/2016

###.data    0x10000000          # BUG: does weird things in mars
###.align   2
    .data
Array1:     .space      1000
Ae:
str1:       .asciiz     "This is assignment 6 \n"
str2:       .asciiz     "The value of a["
str5:       .asciiz     "] is: "
str3:       .asciiz     "Arithmetic overflow"
str4:       .asciiz     "Enter n: "
str6:       .asciiz     "Restarting ...\n"
clean:      .asciiz     "clean occurs"

strlge:     .asciiz     "count too large -- maximum is "
strnl:      .asciiz     "\n"

###.text    0x00400000
    .text
###.align   2                   # BUG: flagged by assembler
    .globl  main

main:

    # show the assignment
    li      $v0,4                   # load 4 to $v0 to begin printing
    la      $a0,str1                # load address of string to be printed
    syscall

    # prompt user
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str4
    syscall

    # get size of Array1
    la      $t6,Array1              # get base address of array
    la      $s6,Ae                  # get address of array end
    sub     $s6,$s6,$t6             # get array size in bytes
    srl     $s6,$s6,2               # get array count

    # Read in N
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $t6,$v0

    bgt     $t6,$s6,toolarge        # is length okay? no, fly

    addi    $t6,$t6,1               # N += 1

    li      $s6,1                   # BUG: this never changes

    # assign array values
    li      $t0,0                   # value 0
    li      $t1,1                   # value 1
    li      $t2,2                   # value 2
    li      $t3,4                   # value N = 4
    # addi $t6, $zero, 10   # End value a[9] is the 10th element

    # byte addressing issue
    mul     $a0,$t0,$t3             # $t0 *4
    mul     $a1,$t1,$t3             # $t1 *4
    mul     $a2,$t2,$t3             # $t2 *4

    # store first 3 elements of the array
    sw      $t0,Array1($a0)         # a[0] = 0
    sw      $t1,Array1($a1)         # a[1] = 1
    sw      $t1,Array1($a2)         # a[2] = 1

    li      $v1,4                   # get value 4

    li      $t4,3

# begin loop algorithm to generate rest of array values
loop:

    # End condition
    beq     $t4,$t6,done

    # generate n - k
    subi    $t0,$t4,1               # n-1
    subi    $t1,$t4,2               # n-2
    subi    $t2,$t4,3               # n-3

    # byte addressing issue
    mul     $t0,$t0,$v1             # $t0 *4
    mul     $t1,$t1,$v1             # $t1 *4
    mul     $t2,$t2,$v1             # $t2 *4

    # store the values
    lw      $a0,Array1($t0)         # a[n-1]
    lw      $a1,Array1($t1)         # a[n-2]
    lw      $a2,Array1($t2)         # a[n-3]

    # begin addition
    add     $t5,$a0,$a1             # a[n-1] + a[n-2]
    ###beq      $s7,$s6,cleanup
    add     $t5,$t5,$a2             # a[n-1] + a[n-2] + a[n-3]
    ###beq      $s7,$s6,cleanup

    # save the result in the proper location
    mul     $a3,$t4,$v1             # $a3 = $t4 * 4
    sw      $t5,Array1($a3)

    # increment N
    addi    $t4,$t4,1

    # repeat
    j       loop

done:
    mul     $t6,$t6,$v1             # $t6 * 4
    lw      $t7,Array1($a3)

    # print str2
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str2
    syscall

    # print value of answer
    # BUG -- answer is always 1
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s6
    syscall

    # print str5
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str5
    syscall

    # Print contents of $t7
    addi    $a0,$t7,0               # Move the product to $a0
    li      $v0,1                   # code for printing register
    syscall

    j       finish

# tell user to cut down the size
toolarge:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,strlge
    syscall

    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s6
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,strnl
    syscall

    j       main

restart:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,str6
    syscall

cleanup:
    li      $t0,0
    li      $t1,0
    li      $t2,0
    li      $t3,0
    li      $t4,0
    li      $t5,0
    li      $t6,0
    li      $t7,0

    li      $s0,0
    li      $s1,0
    li      $s2,0
    li      $s3,0
    li      $s4,0
    li      $s5,0
    li      $s6,0
    li      $s7,0

    li      $v0,0
    li      $v1,0
    li      $a0,0
    li      $a1,0
    li      $a2,0
    li      $a3,0

    j       main

finish:
    # End program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# Begin arithmetic overflow handling
    .ktext  0x80000180

    move    $k0,$v0                 # Save $v0 value
    move    $k1,$a0                 # Save $a0 value

    # Print overflow message
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,kstr1
    syscall

    # print PC in hex
    li      $v0,34
    mfc0    $a0,$14                 # Coproc 0 $14 has address of trapping inst
    syscall

    # print newline
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,kstr2
    syscall

    la      $a0,restart             # get the restart address
    mtc0    $a0,$14                 # Store new address back into $14

    move    $v0,$k0                 # Restore $v0
    move    $a0,$k1                 # Restore $a0

    eret

    .kdata
kstr1:      .asciiz     "\nhandler: Arithmetic overflow -- PC = "
kstr2:      .asciiz     "\n"
```

---

*Note:* I did *not* fix the bug where `s6` remains constant. You'll have to figure out what you want for that.